# Using Button throwing a NullReferenceException; am I missing something?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm getting a error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I think i'm not initialize something.

This is the code; the error is on line `if (btn.Background.Equals(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0))))`:

```
private void vbOpenGuiaMaestro_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = default(Button);
    if (btn.Background.Equals(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0))))
    {
         btn.Background = materiaColor;
         btn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
         stckTeachersGuideClosed.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         stckTeachersGuideOpened.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
         btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
         btn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 140, 140, 140));
    }
 }
```

Comment: btn is null? Could you please make sure it's the right control?

Comment: What is the value of btn if you put a breakpoint on that line? I'm guessing it's null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Default no it isn't a duplicate. This is a specific question about the written code. Your link is a general theoretical question.

Comment: @Recipe just looking at the Related questions I see 10 questions with a similar title. The one I linked has the most complete answer (IMO) and that is why I tagged that one. Maybe not an exact duplicate, but this kind of question has been asked here **many** times before and by just browsing some of the other ones the OP should be able to resolve his issue. To me, yet another *"Object reference not set"* question just adds noise to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your **sender is StackPanel** and you're casting it to Button. Wrong!

```
StackPanel stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
if(stackPanel != null)
{
        if (stackPanel.Background.Equals(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0))))
        {
            stackPanel.Background = materiaColor;               
            stckTeachersGuideClosed.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            stckTeachersGuideOpened.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            stackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
}
```

Comment: But the stackPanel does not contain a definition for Foreground.

Comment: Can you post your XAML here to see what exactly the structure is?

Answer (score 6):

```
default(Button)
```

gives you `null` as `Button` is a reference type. I guess you wanted

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
```

Comment: his problem occurs before initializing it to default(Button)

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy No, the first if is just a copy of the actual line, this is just unclear because of the formatting

Comment: This should probably check whether the type of sender actually is `Button` before casting.

Comment: There will be no cast exception if this event handler is bound to a Button. sender will always be Button.

Comment: Ok is fine the error is fix bot now I receiving another error: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button'.

Comment: Not good, sounds like your button is inside the stack panel (?) but without the actual xaml it is not easy to help here.

Answer (score 0):

You error is here `Button btn = default(Button);`. This is setting the button to `null` since that's the default for the class.

You should instead be casting the `sender` object as `Button` and then verifying the `sender` is not null (in case the event was not originated by a button).

```
var btn = sender as Button;
if (btn != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: btn is always send null.

Answer (score 0):

In the `sender` object, you have a reference to the control on the UI that triggered this event. It is of type object but you can cast it to your needed type (in this case, `Button`).

So get a reference to the button like this :

```
var btn = (Button) sender;
```

Alternatively, you can also use :

```
var btn = sender as Button;
```

The difference is that in the first case, if the cast is unsuccesful, it will throw you an `InvalidCastException`. In the 2nd way, it will silently try to cast it even if the type you specify was not the intended one but will crash further on when the object will be misused.